# Determining success/failure with node.js function async.retry

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I'm studying the node.js module async, but I have some problems with the function async.retry.

According to its [github docs](https://github.com/caolan/async#retry),
the function will continue trying the task until it succeeds or chances are used up. But how can my task tell success or failure?

I tried the code below:

```
var async = require('async');

var opts = {
    count : -3
};

async.retry(5, function (cb, results) {
    ++this.count;
    console.log(this.count, results);
    if (this.count > 0) cb(null, this.count);
    else cb();
}.bind(opts), function (err, results) {
   console.log(err, results);
});
```

I expect it to run until `count === 1`, but it always prints this:

```
-2 undefined
undefined undefined
```

So how can I use the function correctly?

Comment: Thank you for showing the use of `bind` in the async task. I was just trying to figure out how to pass arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want your `else`-branch to fail. For that, you need to pass something to the error parameter; currently you just pass `undefined` which signals success - and that's what you get back.

```
async.retry(5, function (cb, results) {
    ++this.count;
    console.log(this.count, results);
    if (this.count > 0) cb(null, this.count);
    else cb(new Error("count too low"));
}.bind(opts), function (err, results) {
   console.log(err, results);
});
```

Comment: What completely escapes me is why it's not in the documentation that the callback should be the first parameter of the function you're retrying.

Comment: @Ali: Uh, actually it's [right there](https://github.com/caolan/async#retry): "*`task(callback, results)`  - A function which receives two arguments: (1) a callback …*"